# How to remove TextChangedListener for Edit Text in monodroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have used `AddTextChangedListener` for editing text:

```
edit_text.AddTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher());
```

Now I want to remove the TextChangedListener`for the`EditText`.

I've tried using the code below, but I had no luck with it.

```
edit_text.RemoveTextChangedListener(NumberTextWatcher);
```

Comment: try this edit_text.addTextChangedListener(null);

Comment: Not working @arun.I am unable to text into my text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the reference to your `NumberTextWatcher` somewhere in order to later remove it

```
//Field that stores the reference
private readonly NumberTextWatcher watcher = new NumberTextWatcher();

//Adds the listener
edit_text.AddTextChangedListener(watcher);

//Later in your code you can simply remove it like this:
edit_text.RemoveTextChangedListener(watcher);
```